# Obter índice do elemento no Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou tentando usar o método [indexOf](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/CollectionType/s:FeRq_Ss14CollectionType_SsS_7indexOfuRq_S__Fq_FzFzqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSbGSqqq_Ss9Indexable5Index_) para saber o índice de um objeto dentro do array mas não sei quais parâmetro(s) passar.

Meu código:

```
/// Struct that define the track model 
struct Track {
  let songID: Int
  let songName: String

  init(songID id: Int, songName name: String) {
    songID = id
    songName = name
  }
}

/// Struct that define the playlist model 
struct Playlist {
  var tracks = [Track]()
}

// MARK: - Exemplo
let s = Track(songID: 1, songName: "song1")
let t = Track(songID: 2, songName: "song2")
let u = Track(songID: 2, songName: "song3")
let v = Track(songID: 2, songName: "song4")

var playlist = Playlist.init(tracks: [s, t, u, v])

// se eu passar o objeto t da o seguinte erro: 
// Cannot convert value of type 'Track' to expected argument type '@noescape (Track) throws -> Bool'
if let index = playlist.tracks.indexOf(t){
  print(index)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que especificar qual é propriedade que você quer comparar, como no seu exemplo a única propriedade com valor único é o nome, eu usei ele pra comparar.

```
if let index = playlist.tracks.indexOf({$0.songName == t.songName}){
  print(index)
}
```

**Exemplo funcional**: http://swiftstub.com/910951409

Comment: Valeu demais !  Em algum momento eu tinha tentado algo parecido com isso que você mostrou mas não funcionou, mas sua resposta funcionou 100%